# Why is it so hard for me to get a good answer?

Tags: discussion

I am new to the SO community and needed some answers about my [swift coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714921/how-to-link-a-boolean-value-to-the-on-off-state-of-a-uiswitch-in-swift) and received one answer. I put in the code suggested in the answer and it did not work. I commented on the answer saying this and no edit to the answer or extra help was given. I added the rest of my code, hoping it would help. The only response was an edit to implement the code that was already suggested. I would like to put a bounty to attract better answers, but I only have 6 reputation points. I only joined the SO community to ask this question. The project is currently at a standstill.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the programming language you're using, but if i came across a javascript question with that much code, i would move to another question without reading. The same thing may be happening to you. I would suggest trying to narrow the issue down a bit more while waiting for someone to come along and help.

Comment: @KevinB The original post (the one that I got the unhelpful answer for) only had the bare minimum code. Swift sometimes requires multiple documents to be linked so I thought it would be helpful, perhaps the problem lay somewhere else.

Comment: This isn't good: *The project is currently at a standstill.* For almost three weeks? You need to be exploring alternatives and other knowledge centers, not waiting for an answer here.

Comment: @MichealPetrotta I have been looking at Apple's documentation and all around the web. This language is relitively new so that might be the problem. I have also been trying other things.

Comment: Swift is all of 2 months old. There aren't that many experts in the language yet to answer questions.

Comment: The code in the answer should work, by the way: if it crashed, it might be another (unrelated) issue. Check that you've linked the `UISwitch` to the `IBAction`.

Comment: You picked a brand new beta language for your project and you're surprised that help isn't available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no exact answer to this type of thing, and it varies from problem to problem, but there are a few things you could try here.

First of all, you don't need your whole View Controller class: narrow it down to the information that is relevant to your problem and explain *why* it is relevant. If your question is more than 50% code, you probably have some work to do.

> The project is currently at a standstill.

That's not good: as a programmer, you should be continually searching for different ways to solve a problem and to get around problems you run into. Don't rely on the Stack Overflow monkeys to solve all of your problems for you.

You should be regularly editing your question with new information that you come across as you try to solve the problem, and your post will be bumped to the top of the queue each time you do so, bringing it in front of fresh eyes. If you solve the answer on your own, consider [answering your own question](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to provide others who run into the same problem with a viable solution.

> I would like to put a bounty to attract better answers

That's precisely what you should do: the minimum amount of reputation for a [bounty](//stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is 50 and you gain the [privilege to set one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) at 75 rep. I understand that gaining that much reputation in a timeframe that is reasonable when your project is `at a standstill` can be daunting, but your problem partly stems from this:

> I only joined the SO community to ask this question.

People donate their time, skills, and energy to help you solve your problems for free. The least you could do is edit a couple of posts or answer a question or two. Why should we help you solve your question if you're not going to stick around afterward?

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I now realize that my word choose was not the best. I initially joined to ask this question, I plan on sticking around to help other people. I also realize that I may have been a little inpatient, considering that swift is so new. I will continue my search for answers with these things in mind.